# Can Ubuntu Server be run through Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: server, nginx

I have both Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop on a hard drive. But I was wondering if there is a way to have the server running while I am on the Desktop version?

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

You can [chroot](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/chroot.8.html) into the server system, but getting it to work properly as a server this way would be complicated and unworthwhile.

Instead you should probably simply **install the packages you need in the desktop system**.

The only difference between Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu desktop is what packages are installed. An Ubuntu desktop system can be used as a server (and likewise, a GUI can be installed in Ubuntu Server).

For example, if you need the Apache web server, you can install the `apache2` package.

For nginx (you tagged your question [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) but didn't mention it explicitly), you can choose between the following packages: [`nginx-full`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/nginx-full), [`nginx-light`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/nginx-light), and [`nginx-naxsi`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/nginx-naxsi). Related packages you may want or not want (depending on your needs) are [`nginx-naxsi-ui`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/nginx-naxsi-ui) and [`nginx-extras`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/nginx-extras).

### If your goal is to create a teaching/learning or development box:

You [later mentioned](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278989/can-ubuntu-server-be-run-through-ubuntu-desktop/278991#comment350312_278991):

> This isn't for production, but due to my job, I will need to learn how
> to setup/update/manage servers, so I thought I would turn an old PC
> into a server. I haven't used anything like virtual box as you cannot
> access it remotely (as far as I am aware).

VirtualBox (or another virtualization solution, if you prefer) *is actually the best thing to use in this situation*.

You *can* actually use VirtualBox and access it remotely, and since your goal is to practice with a system that *works like a production server*, it seems that's probably what you ought to do. The simplest and easiest way to make services on a virtual machine accessible to the outside physical network is to set up the VM's internet connection as *bridged* (rather than NAT).

As [the VirtualBox manual says](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#idp19399280):

> [...] open the Settings dialog of a virtual machine, go to the
> "Network" page and select "Bridged network" in the drop down list for
> the "Attached to" field. Finally, select desired host interface from
> the list at the bottom of the page, which contains the physical
> network interfaces of your systems.

Feel free to post a new question about this if you have trouble getting servers on a VirtualBox guest system with a bridged network adapater accessible from the outside. Usually, there are no complications.

While VirtualBox and other virtualization solutions generally *can* use an entire physical drive as a "virtual" device for a virtual machine--even, usually, an internal drive--you're not likely to succeed at making a VM use the single partition of a pre-existing system as its hard drive. So you'll have to create a new VM and install Ubuntu Server; you probably will not be able to make your VM run the copy of Ubuntu Server that is already installed. (Installing in the VM is easy though--it's the same procedure as installing on a physical machine, like you have done.)

Comment: Yes, I will be using Nginx, sorry for not mentioning this. But this all looks very complicated, but it should work in exactly the same way, and i could also ssh into it? (Sorry, i'm kinda new to this)

Comment: @Melloorr Yes. If you want to SSH in, install the `openssh-server` package. But ...is this a production server? A production server should generally not be on the same box that's used for desktop work, which is why the server version of Ubuntu doesn't ship with a GUI pre-installed.

Comment: This isn't for production, but due to my job, I will need to learn how to setup/update/manage servers, so I thought I would turn an old PC into a server. I haven't used anything like virtual box as you cannot access it remotely (as far as I am aware).

Comment: @Melloorr I've added the information about how virtualization really is the best solution for your situation, and how you *can* make servers running on a VM in VirtualBox accessible to the outside physical network, to my answer. (It was important, and I decided it should constitute the second part of my answer.)