# How should I use Ubuntu Server in a VM for Ethereum LLL development with Ubuntu desktop as a host?

Tags: server, virtualbox

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278989/can-ubuntu-server-be-run-through-ubuntu-desktop/278991#278991), but I still want to double-check to see what the best solution is for my needs.

I installed Virtual Box, but all the options are in 32 bit with my 64 bit system, and there is only one option for Ubuntu.

What should I do if I want to use Ubuntu Desktop for normal desktop use but use the terminal regularly for [Ethereum LLL development](https://media.consensys.net/installing-ethereum-compilers-61d701e78f6)? One option is to log in as the root user with method 2 [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Become-Root-in-Linux), every time I want root access. This options works so I will continue to use that, but I also want to see if there is a better option (although typing in `su -` and the root password every time I open the terminal is not that big a deal).

Comment: For 64-bit guests see https://askubuntu.com/questions/41550/how-do-i-run-a-64-bit-guest-in-virtualbox -  enable VT-x/AMD-v in BIOS and in the VM settings.

Comment: Why do you want to use a seperate machine for development? There may be very good reasons to do so - but all packages for ubuntu server is available for the desktop as well...

Comment: I was thinking that I could stay logged in as the root user on the server machine for convenience, but even then, I may not always want to use the root user, so I might just keep using the desktop.